# Does XFCE allow transitions for panels and/or icons?

Tags: xubuntu, icons, xfce, customization

I want to know if XFCE can be configured to allow zooming/scaling of icons when the user hovers over them, similar to the effect(s) shown on a Mac dock.

Also, I wonder if my left panel (of course it is automatically hidden) could be set to show/hide a bit more gradually, such as how **jQuery** *slide* animation works?

I hear tell of config files for the DE, but I haven't delved into them just yet. I haven't run an XFCE desktop in a couple of years; I usually prefer WM-only, using Openbox + xdm, but I'm converting back for the moment. I'm just a humble web developer and I miss the quick productivity (and undue clutter) of icons all over the place. Anyway, I still want them to look pretty!

Note: I don't know why Tux looks like a monkey on my wallpaper, but I really like that grey. Eh!

[image: Hey, it looks like Unity, but is much faster and less spy-y!]

Comment: You could always install `cairo-dock` which allows for that Mac dock type of experience.  `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock`

Comment: phew! That thing is buggy but boy, is it neat. I do like it, though it doesn't directly answer the question of whether I can customize my XFCE panel to do similar things. It's very twitchy and picky but, +1 for the suggestion which is a very nice workaround. Cheers! Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it is buggy, but I like it too.  If you need it in OpenGL mode, launch it with `cairo-dock -o`.  

I don't know if there is a way to get the panels in Xfce to do the similar things like the dock does.  I have been using Xfce now for quite a while and I have never figured anything out for that.  We can wait and see if someone comes along and knows.  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly no. To this answered date, Xfce has limited to no transitions for panels and icons. Nothing fancy, besides minimizing active applications window to the panel in Xfce.

### Xfce allows delay

Delay is a transition or pseudo-animation in Xfce that I have tried before. This is documented as part of theming Xfce panel in [this page of Xfce Docs](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/theming).

> **XfcePanelWindow**
>
> The normal panel window.
>
> .gtkrc-2.0
>
> ```
> style "xfce-panel-window-style"
> {
>   # Time in miliseconds before the panel will unhide on an enter event
>   XfcePanelWindow::popup-delay = 225
>
>   # Time in miliseconds before the panel will hide on a leave event
>   XfcePanelWindow::popdown-delay = 350
>
>   # Size of autohide window in pixels
>   XfcePanelWindow::autohide-size = 3
> }
> class "XfcePanelWindow" style "xfce-panel-window-style"
> ```

Requirement: Xfce must enable the option to automatically hide the panel. In Xfce 4.12, delay will work for the hide option `Always` but will *not* work for `Intelligently`.

Following the requirement, do these steps:

1. Create a file at `$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0`, then copy and paste the provided code (as quoted).
2. Change the respective values for `popup-delay`, `popdown-delay` and `autohide-size`.
3. Restart the panel by running `xfce4-panel --restart` to take effect.

### Xfce allows opacity

Opacity is another transition that can be applied to Xfce panel.

Requirement: Xfce must enable compositing for opacity to work. In **Settings > Window Manager Tweaks > Compositor**, ensure that "Enable display compositing" is checked.

Following the requirement, do these steps:

1. In **Panel Preferences**, look under **Appearance > Opacity**.
2. Adjust the slider for "Enter:" or "Leave:" to your liking.
3. Click **Close** to finish.

The screenshot below shows the panel becomes less opaque when the mouse cursor leaves the panel (left) and becomes fully opaque when the mouse cursor enters the panel.

[image: Xfce panel with different opacity]

Besides delay and opacity for Xfce panel, I am not aware of other options to customize transitions and animations in Xfce. To make up for the missing features in Xfce, install [`plank`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=plank&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all). Plank is a simple dock, which has both features of hiding animation and icon zoom transition that you want.

Related posts:

- [XFCE - Autohide Animations on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267828/125388)

Comment: Fantastic. Answered all my questions, and thank you for the links/ references. I will look at them and sorry if I made a duplicate; I did not come across them when searching through these forums. Cheers!

Comment: @PSmith I'd refined my search and clarified that your question is unique. The links I had mentioned are relevant for desktop environments of any distro, which you might not find on Ask Ubuntu after all. No worries.